# str object is not callable python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I have tried looking around for an answer however the questions on here either seemed to advanced (I'm new to Python) or because of redefining what something meant which I couldn't catch in my script. Here is the code-

```
a = float(input("Enter the length(in inches)"))
b = float(input("Enter the width(in inches)"))
print ()
print ("The area of your shape is: "(a*b))
```

I am getting the error *TypeError: 'str' object is not callable*.

It is a simple script, I know, but it's a work in progress.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you're using Python 3,

```
print ("The area of your shape is: ", (a*b))
#                                   ^
```

You forgot a comma.

Answer (score 1):

You can print the value either with:

```
print ("The area of your shape is: ", (a*b))
```

or with

```
print ("The area of your shape is: {}".format(a*b))
```

Comment: or if you want it to work as far back as python 2.6, `"{0}"`.